# Jquery Validate not always returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a button that triggers the jquery validation plugin. The problem is that it always returns true, unless the fields are empty. It ignores the rules that are parsed.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/835/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myForm').validate({
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    password: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    }
  });

  $('#validateForm').click(function() {
    var isValid = $("#myForm").valid();
    alert(isValid);
  });
});
```

In fact you can delete my `validate()` function and the same behaviour is present.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/836/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#validateForm').click(function() {
    var isValid = $("#myForm").valid();
    alert(isValid);
  });
});
```

This question has been asked before, but doesn't answer my question:

[jquery validate - remote always returns true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681507/jquery-validate-remote-always-returns-true)

[jQuery Validation always returns true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563586/jquery-validation-always-returns-true)

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: Your button type is submit, it redirecting before validate, you can prevent default submit or change type to button or call validator function in form onSumit

Comment: @whoami no errors, just always returns true, even when rules aren't adhered to.

Comment: @NitinDhomse the "validate form" button isn't submit type and isn't within the form. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It worked when you add the rules sub object:

[jquery validate documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules)

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/837/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myForm').validate({
  rules:{
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      }
    }
  });

  $('#validateForm').click(function() {
    var isValid = $("#myForm").valid();
    alert(isValid);
  });

});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.